# Eclipse: "Run as" does not display the list elements (such as "Run as android application")

Tags: eclipse, runas

This morning I've updated my Ubuntu version and now I can't run my application from eclipse.

The problem is that the list that appears when I click on "Run As" is empty and I can't run anything.

How I can solve this problem?

The only error that I can see, tell me:

```
An internal error occurred during: "Compute launch button tooltip".
org/eclipse/cdt/core/model/CoreModel
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Run command:

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install tzdata-java
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because eclipse doesn't detect you'r application goal, If installed eclipse supports what you want to run, you can reach it from "Run As -> Run Configurations..." then select you'r application goal to run and configure it, 
it need some application settings up to what application want.

Comment: Many thanks for the answer, but I tried to reinstall both eclipse and java jdk and android sdk. THe error remain the same. Why eclipse doesn't detect my application goal if before the ubuntu update all works well? Many thanks...