# C++ in eclipse: After an update?: CDT errors

Tags: c++, eclipse

Since yesterday my eclipse does not work anymore for c++ projects ( After a restart of the computer because of general updates). I work with ubuntu. Re-installation and with a new installation of 
download.eclipse.org/tools/cdt/releases/indigo and subclipse.tigris.org/update_1.8.x or ...1.6.x (see https://askubuntu.com/questions/119754/software-location-after-installing-via-ubuntu-software-center) does not help. I also uninstalled tzdata-java which didn't helped (compare http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/912544/).

I tried to do the following http://subclipse.tigris.org/wiki/JavaHL, but I was unable to change the eclipse.ini file from read only to writable.

The problems are the following. If I want to make target (create) of an existing project it gives the error message: 'Compute launche button tooltip' has encountered a problem. An internal error occured during: "Compite launch button tooltip" under details: "**An internal error occurred during: "Compute launch button tooltip".
org/eclipse/cdt/core/model/CoreModel**".

Another error message is (if I want to close the project): 
"An error has occured. See error log for more details" under details "**An error has occurred. See error log for more details. org/eclipse/cdt/core/model/ICElement**".

If I want to create a new c++ project is gives the error message:
Problem Opening Wizard The selected wizard could not be started." details: "**The selected wizard could not be started.
Plug-in org.eclipse.cdt.ui was unable to load class org.eclipse.cdt.ui.wizards.CCProjectWizard.
An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.eclipse.cdt.ui (229).**"

I copied the whole existing folder to my macbook (I just used texlipse on this one so far) and it does not work.

I am looking forward to your help and ideas! Thanks.

Comment: I would do a clean reinstall of Eclipse. These errors are not really programming errors, but internal errors of the IDE.

Comment: I did the reinstall with the Ubuntu Software Center and with the terminal. And after a new installation I still have the problem. Therefore I tried after the deinstallation to find maybe more eclipse files. When I do "locate eclipse" in the terminal there are still many folders shown. E.g. /var/lib/dpkg/info/eclipse-jdt.listrm:   If I want to remove one it says e.g.        " remove write-protected regular file `eclipse-jdt_3.7.2-1_i386.deb'? yes
rm: cannot remove `eclipse-jdt_3.7.2-1_i386.deb': Permission denied". How do I do a clean reinstall?

Comment: I tried to delete it with rm -r eclipse* when I was in the current folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
apt-get --reinstall install tzdata-java
```

Source: [Eclipse: "Run as" does not display the list elements (such as "Run as android application")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12404216/elipse-run-as-does-not-display-the-list-elements-such-as-run-as-android-app)

(Worked for me)