# Eclipse - "compute launch button tooltip" error

Tags: java, eclipse, android-sdk-2.1

I'm trying to run Android SDK with Eclipse for the first time.
I have never used Eclipse before and I'm running into the following error message over and over again, with no specific trigger: "compute launch button tooltip has encountered a problem".

See screenshot attached.

I tried to Google it but I can't find a solution. It's driving me crazy, please help.
I'm using `Ubuntu 12.04 LTS`. I tried re-installing Eclipse, same thing.

Comment: Can you provide your JDK version ?

Comment: version 7 if I'm not mistaken @Stephan

Answer (score 4):

See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12406787/1020470) to a similar question with the same error. It worked for me. Solution was to run:

```
$ sudo apt-get --reinstall install tzdata-java
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into same problem. I had the latest update of `OpenJDK (1.7)`
I've downloaded the Oracle JDK 1.7 `rpm` package from oracle
converted it to `deb` package using `alien`

```
alien -d -c rpm-package.rpm
```

then in eclipse selected 1.7 version and searched for relevant JREs
it solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try using JRE6 instead of 7. Solved it for me.