# Error message while opening a project in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I was trying to open a project by clicking on it(ie. expanding the project folder).I get this message

[image]

Any suggestions for this problem?

Comment: Check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12481730/eclipse-compute-launch-button-tooltip-error

Comment: I tried it but its for the ubandu version of eclipse and I tried changing my JRE version,but didnt work either

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install tzdata-java
```

Answer (score 0):

U should try this:
uninstall your eclipse and reinstall it. may be your eclipse is not supported by your hardware specifications

Comment: Thanx @Manasi but I have been using eclipse in my computer for a long time and its well supported in my computer.Its not the problem I guess..

Comment: Why not reinstall? It may only take 1 hour and free of charge, and forget about the complexity of searching for the real issue.

Comment: -1. Answers like that should never be posted. Essentially they say: I have no clue, but hey, try something random!

Answer (score 0):

Scala plugin does not honour preferences for Preferences -> Run/debug -> Launching.

For instance, Launch Operation -> select Launch the previously launched application.

The popup 'Editor does not have main type' appears because the filter applied to the launcher was *.scala, so control was always passed to ScalaLaunchShortcut, which then didn't find any main class. Added a property to the launcher to filter for scala editors which have main methods, and if there are none, then the default behaviour for JDT launching (launch previous etc) works correctly.